# Multivalue field with Twig and its length

Tags: theming, 8

I am playing around with Twig and D8. I created a content type called `community` and it contains a field called `field_banner_images` which is an image field with a max limit of 10 images.

I am trying to get the length of `field_banner_images` via Twig, but the number I am receiving is incorrect. My current node has 10 images on it. It also has alt text enabled if that makes a difference.

I created a file called `node--community.html.twig` and inside I have:

`{{ content.field_banner_images|length }}`

which outputs 26, which is wrong. I would expect it to output 10.

Furthermore, I add

```
{% for item in content.field_banner_images %}
  <span class="banner-img">{{ content.field_banner_images[loop.index0] }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

and while it does output the 10 images wrapped in span elements, I also get 16 empty span elements since it is looping 26 times.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `node--community--field-banner-images.html.twig` and `{{ kint() }}` to see if you can get the value of the index.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. You are not getting pure values in your field. In order for that you would need {{ attribute('getValue', content.field_banner_images)|length }} or something like that but I highly doubt that will work. Simply put, you cannot do the same thing in Twig as you can in PHP. Use hook_preprocess_HOOK to add any variables that you need in your templates.

Comment: The issue on d.o. https://www.drupal.org/node/2776307

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How to count in page or node template**

`content` is the render array of the fields, that is build according to the view mode you have configured. The render array contains a lot of additional elements, that are not field items.

If you want to count the items in the field that are in the database, use the `node` object:

In php:

```
$node->field_banner_images->count();
```

In twig:

`count()` is not on the whitelist of allowed methods. Use .getvalue() instead, which gets the complete field array and count the array keys with the filter length:

```
{{ node.field_banner_images.getvalue|length }}
```

**Better solution with field template**

But you don't have to code the loop yourself in the node template, you can add the wrapper in the field twig.

Put the complete field in the node template:

```
{{ content.field_banner_images }}
```

And then put the wrapper in:

**field--field-banner-images.html.twig**

```
{% for item in items %}
    <span>{{ item.content }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

You can remove the content of the field twig and replace it with the code above. You know the content of this field and you don't need the div containers, when you want span's.

Answer (score 0):

FYI

This doesn't work.

```
{{ node.field_banner_images.count }}
```

Instead you can do something like that :

```
{{ node.field_banner_images|length }}
```